# Should encoded URL arguments/parameters be used to comprise a URL for a request?

Tags: python, url, parameters, python-requests

For instance, the (parameter, argument) combination (room_types, Entire home/apt) is encoded as `&room_types%5B%5D=Entire%20home%2Fapt` when an [airbnb search](https://www.airbnb.com/s/los-angeles?guests=1&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&ss_id=53hdz81s&source=bb&page=1&allow_override%5B%5D=&room_types%5B%5D=Entire%20home%2Fapt&s_tag=Tz9WXaZl) is used.

Would there be any issues with using an entire URL with those encoded parameters, or do they need to be decoded and used in a params dictionary with a `requests.request("GET")` call?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any issues. The `params` interface is provided to make your life easier in the common case. You can even have both, and Requests will [append the encoded `params` after an &](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/d6f4818c0b40bc6c00433c013b7daaea83b2cd51/requests/models.py#L426-L431).

Do note that there may be multiple ways to URL-encode a given string (for example, a theoretical `%45%6E%74%69%72%65%20%68%6F%6D%65` decodes to the same string as `Entire%20home`), but this is usually not a problem.